# Practical C++ Sockets or Virtual machine?

Tags: c++, sockets, windows-xp, virtual

I'm trying to use this library to the sockets in c + +: Practical C++ Sockets (http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/practical/CSockets/practical/)
I tried a simple example of a multicast sender and receiver multicast

- on Mac OSX I send and receive multicast msg.
- I created a virtual machine with Windows XP and I feel the same example.

the message is sent but the receiver does not receive anything. In your opinion, is a problem of virtual machine or library on windows? (if I try to sniff packets on the virtual machine I see the message sent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multicast only works on the same subnet so make sure your virtual machine has the same subnet as your main computer. This is why Bonjour by apple only works with devices on the same subnet because it uses multicast.